# windowShouldClose(_:) never called

Tags: swift3, xcode8, osx-elcapitan

I want to prevent user close the main window (and quit the app) while a countdown is running.
I have read posts about that but unfortunately none of the methods explained will work.
I think I do the right thing but windowShouldClose is never called unlike the other two functions. I am desperate.  :)
Here's my code in the NSWindowController:

```
import Cocoa

class WindowController: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate {

override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    print("Window did load")
    self.window?.delegate = self
}

func windowShouldClose(sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
    print("Window should close")
    let alert = NSAlert.init()
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "No")
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "Yes")
    alert.informativeText = "Close the window?"
    let response = alert.runModal()
    if response == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("Window will close")
}

func windowDidChangeScreen(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("Window did change screen")
}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

*`windowShouldClose(_:)` is never called* because you declared it as `windowShouldClose(:)`

In Swift 3 the signature of the [delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate/1419380-windowshouldclose) is

```
func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Vous êtes mon sauveur !  :)

Answer (score 0):

my two cents for Swift5 / Xcode 10.

If:
 - you are using NSViewController (as in iOS....)
 - you want to use logic in a NSViewController derived class (instead of in  NSWindowController)

is useless setting delegate in "windowDidLoad" or "awakeFromNib".
(I need it in a multiplatform iOS / OS project)

so:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, **NSWindowDelegate** {
```

you must set it in viewWillAppear..

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
        // we choose to delegate ourselves
        let window = self.view.window
        window!.delegate = self
    }
```

(even if it will be called even on resuming from background.. but works.)

***Note:***

a) seems a better way to completely remove close button, in some cases:

```
window!.styleMask.remove(.closable)
```

b) Apple Review does not allow to remove Close button (but maay be useful)